# How to avoid global delaunay check in conforming triangulation?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computational-geometry, discrete-mathematics, triangulation

I implemented a conforming (i.e. it creates Steiner points using Ruppert's algorithm) delaunay triangulator, which is working, but there is one step I am doing that I straight up don't understand and suggests something is broken.

After introducing a circumcenter of a triangle, I am having to check the entire mesh and restore the Delaunay property manually. I don't understand why I would need to do this?

I have tested all the subroutines the algorithm depends on, so I know the issue is coming from the logic of the algorithm itself.

This is my implementation in rust:

```rs
pub fn conforming_delaunay_triangulation_as_mesh(
    points: &dyn Fn(usize) -> Vec3,
    point_count: usize,
    segments: &dyn Fn(usize) -> [usize; 2],
    segment_count: usize,
    angle_constraint: f32,
    area_constraint: f32,
) -> HalfMesh<Vec3, (), ()>
{
    // Compute a triangulation.
    let mesh = constrained_delaunay_triangulation_hollow_as_mesh(
        points,
        point_count,
        segments,
        segment_count,
    );

    // Sort all *bad* faces from worst to best in apriority queue.
    // === 1. Score all triangles and filter the bad ones ===
    let mut bad_face_queue = PQueue::new();
    for triangle in mesh
        .iter_faces()
        .filter(|t| triangle_is_bad(t, angle_constraint, area_constraint))
    {
        let weight = triangle_weight(&triangle);
        bad_face_queue.push(triangle.id(), weight);
    }

    // Find all constrained and boundary segments.
    let mut segment_set: BTreeSet<GeomId<1>> = (0..segment_count)
        .map(|i| {
            let [v1, v2] = segments(i);
            mesh.vert_handle(GeomId::from(v1))
                .shared_hedge(GeomId::from(v2))
                .unwrap()
        })
        .map(|e| e.id().select_even())
        .collect();
    segment_set.extend(
        mesh.iter_edges()
            .filter(|e| e.is_in_boundary_edge())
            .map(|e| e.id()),
    );

    // === Algorithm ===
    while !bad_face_queue.is_empty()
    {
        // === 2. Pop current worst triangle ===
        let (fid, _w) = bad_face_queue.pop().unwrap();
        let points = mesh.face_handle(fid).vertices_tri();
        let circumcenter = osculating_circle(&points[0], &points[1], &points[2]);

        // === 3. Check if the circumcircle encroaches an edge ===
        let mut segment_encroached = false;
        let mut edge = mesh.hedge_handle(GeomId(0));
        for segment in &segment_set
        {
            edge = mesh.hedge_handle(*segment);
            if encroaches(&edge, &circumcenter)
            {
                segment_encroached = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // === 4. If it encroaches the edge, split the edge ===
        if segment_encroached
        {
            let new_edges;
            let vid;
            // Split the edge (check is needed because boundary edges must use special
            // logic).
            if !edge.is_in_boundary_edge()
            {
                (vid, _, new_edges) = edge.split::<f32>();
            }
            else
            {
                (vid, _, new_edges) = edge
                    .get_non_boundary_hedge()
                    .unwrap()
                    .split_boundary::<f32>();
            }

            // Restore Delaunay criterion.
            lawsons_algorithm(vid, &mesh, |e| e.is_in_boundary_edge());
            // We added new faces and changed existing ones, update the queue.
            for face in mesh
                .vert_handle(vid)
                .iter_hedges()
                .filter(|e| !e.is_boundary_hedge())
                .map(|e| e.face())
            {
                if !triangle_is_bad(&face, angle_constraint, area_constraint)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                let weight = triangle_weight(&face);
                bad_face_queue.push(face.id(), weight);
            }
            segment_set.insert(new_edges[1]);
        }
        // === 5. If it does not encroach the edge, split the face ===
        else
        {
            let face = find_containing_triangle(&circumcenter, &mesh);
            if face.is_none()
            {
                continue;
            }
            let face = face.unwrap();
            let vid = face.split_triangle_face::<f32>();
            // Set face to circumcircle:
            let v = mesh.vert_handle(vid);
            v.mutate_data(&circumcenter);

            // Restore Delaunay criterion.
            lawsons_algorithm(vid, &mesh, |e| e.is_in_boundary_edge());
            // TODO(low): why is this necessary?
            for v in mesh.iter_verts()
            {
                lawsons_algorithm(v.id(), &mesh, |e| e.is_in_boundary_edge());
            }

            // We added new faces and changed existing ones, update the queue.
            for face in mesh.vert_handle(vid).iter_hedges().map(|e| e.face())
            {
                if !triangle_is_bad(&face, angle_constraint, area_constraint)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                let weight = triangle_weight(&face);
                bad_face_queue.push(face.id(), weight);
            }
        }
    }

    mesh
}


/// Recursively flips triangles around a determined vertex until all pass the
/// delaunay test (or are constrained).
pub fn lawsons_algorithm<F>(
    source: GeomId<0>,
    mesh: &HalfMesh<Vec3, (), ()>,
    is_constraint_edge: F,
) where
    F: Fn(&HEdgeHandle<Vec3, (), ()>) -> bool,
{
    let mut queue = VecDeque::from_iter(
        mesh.vert_handle(source)
            .iter_hedges()
            .map(|e| e.next().id()),
    );
    while !queue.is_empty()
    {
        let edge_id = queue.pop_front().unwrap();
        let edge_handle = mesh.hedge_handle(edge_id);
        if delaunay_test(&edge_handle)
            && edge_handle.can_flip()
            && !is_constraint_edge(&edge_handle)
        {
            edge_handle.flip();
            queue.push_back(edge_handle.next().id());
            queue.push_back(edge_handle.pair().prev().id());
        }
    }
}
```

The summarizing pseudo code would be:

- Compute a constrained Delaunay triangulation.
- Create a priority queue of bad triangles from worst face to least bad
- Create a set of segments
- While there are bad  triangles:

  - Pop the worst triangle
  - If its circumcenter encroaches a segment in the set, split that segment, add the new segment created by the split to the existing set, restore the Delaunay condition, update face queue.
  - Else, find the face containing the circumcenter, split the face at the circumcenter, restore the Delaunay condition around the circumcenter.
  - *HACK!!!!!* restore the Delaunay cirterion globally across the mesh
  - Update the triangle queue with the faces surrounding the circumcenter.

I don't understand why I need to do the hack. Either my lawson algorithm is incorrect, or I have miss understood something key about the algorithm. I am hoping someone can lend me a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The implementation of lawson's algorithm I had was incorrect, this is the right one:

````rs
/// Recursively flips triangles around a determined vertex until all pass the
/// delaunay test (or are constrained).
pub fn lawsons_algorithm<F>(
    source: GeomId<0>,
    mesh: &HalfMesh<Vec3, (), ()>,
    is_constraint_edge: F,
) where
    F: Fn(&HEdgeHandle<Vec3, (), ()>) -> bool,
{
    let mut queue = VecDeque::from_iter(
        mesh.vert_handle(source)
            .iter_hedges()
            .map(|e| e.face().id()),
    );

    let find_opposite = |face: &FaceHandle<Vec3, (), ()>| {
        face.hedge()
            .iter_loop()
            .find(|e| e.source().id() != source && e.dest().id() != source)
            .unwrap()
    };
    while !queue.is_empty()
    {
        let face_id = queue.pop_front().unwrap();
        if face_id == ABSENT()
        {
            continue;
        }
        let edge_handle = find_opposite(&mesh.face_handle(face_id));
        if delaunay_test(&edge_handle)
            && edge_handle.can_flip()
            && !is_constraint_edge(&edge_handle)
        {
            edge_handle.flip();
            queue.push_back(edge_handle.face().id());
            queue.push_back(edge_handle.pair().face().id());
        }
    }
}
```
````